# Aggregation on one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem with SQL Server to show the details of some data as well as a count value on one column. I can do the aggregation but can't show the rest of the details. Can someone please help me. Thanks.

```
select *
from 
(select temp.machine, count(temp.machine)-1 as job_q from 
(select ab.order_no, ast.machine, product_no, machine_name, quantity as qty, psd as 
planned_start_date, ped as planned_end_date,
    esd as earliest_start_date, time_1, 
    eed as earliest_end_date, eet as earliest_end_time
    from table_ab ab
    left join table_ast ast ON ab.order_no=ast.order_no
    WHERE ab.order_no like 'MO%'
    AND (ast.machine = 'MH6'
    OR ast.machine = 'M5X')
    AND ast.machine NOT like 'OEM%'
    AND machine_name NOT like 'PP2%'
    AND psd > '2021-01-17 00:00:00.000'
    AND ab.machine IS NOT NULL        
    group by ab.order_no, ast.machine, product_no,machine_name, quantity, psd, ped,
    esd, time_1, 
    eed, eet)temp group by temp.machine)tempa order by tempa.machine;
```

The result is:

| machine_no | job_q |
| --- | --- |
| M5X | 7 |
| MH6 | 4 |

But what I need is the other details as well:

| order_no | machine_no | product no | machine_name | job_q |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OR1234 | M5X | PDT-122-1 | BIG_CUTTER | 7 |

Comment: We'd need to see some sample data in order to assist. The obvious answer is to group by all the columns you need. But my guess is that doesn't work, so we need to see how the other data changes and how you select the correct row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use analytical function `count` as follows:

```
select distinct order_no, machine_no, product_no, machine_name, 
       count(temp.machine) over (partition by temp.machine) -1 as job_q 
  from 
 (select ab.order_no, ast.machine, product_no, machine_name, quantity as qty, 
         psd as planned_start_date, ped as planned_end_date,
         esd as earliest_start_date, time_1, 
         eed as earliest_end_date, eet as earliest_end_time
    from table_ab ab
    left join table_ast ast ON ab.order_no=ast.order_no
    WHERE ab.order_no like 'MO%'
    AND (ast.machine = 'MH6'
    OR ast.machine = 'M5X')
    AND ast.machine NOT like 'OEM%'
    AND machine_name NOT like 'PP2%'
    AND psd > '2021-01-17 00:00:00.000'
    AND ab.machine IS NOT NULL        
    group by ab.order_no, ast.machine, product_no,machine_name, quantity, 
             psd, ped, esd, time_1, eed, eet)temp
```